# IDbCommandTreeInterceptor.TreeCreated: How to create Expression equivale Set Name = Name + 'Suffix'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want create a DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause that work equivale SQL `set name = name + '{suffix}'`.

I can use this expression for SetClause: `setClauses.Add(DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(addSuffixColumn, DbExpression.FromString("MyText")));`

It's equivale with `set name = 'MyText'`

My question is, how to I create a SetClause equivale `set name = name + 'MyText'`

Sorry for any unclear. Thanks you!

Comment: If you want C# help to write C# code which is equivalent to SQL code, you need to show the SQL code you want to replicate, the C# code you've tried, the results you have obtained (including any error messages), and explain how those results differ from what you want.

Comment: You're describing what you think the solution looks like, in a way that's hard to understand what you actually want. Change the table mapping convention? Field mapping conventions? You don't need any special code when you map tables and fields using the fluent API or attributes, which leaves conventions. Unless you want to generate UPDATE statements? EF is an ORM. It works with objects, not SQL. If you want to generate `UPDATE tbl1 SET name= name +'foo'` the easiest way is to just write that statement

Comment: Thanks for your comment Nicholas and Panaiotis.
I can use this expression for SetClause: `setClauses.Add(DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(addSuffixColumn, DbExpression.FromString("MyText")));`

It's equivale with `set name = 'MyText'`

My question is, how to I create a SetClause equivale `set name = name + 'MyText'`

Sorry for any unclear. Thanks you!